# Bootstrap grid gets stacked (Rating Bar)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, stacked

**When I shrinks the screen the third column gets stacked bottom. I want three of in horizontal fashion. Please help**
Actually it happens when screen width gets: 358px.

Code:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                 <h5 class="text-right"> 5* </h5>
                 <h5 class="text-right"> 4* </h5>
                 <h5 class="text-right"> 3* </h5>
                 <h5 class="text-right"> 2* </h5>
                 <h5 class="text-right"> 1* </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                 <h5> Research </h5>
                 <h5> Research </h5>
                 <h5> Research </h5>
                 <h5> Research </h5>
                 <h5> Research </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                 <h5> 50 </h5>
                 <h5> 49 </h5>
                 <h5> 38 </h5>
                 <h5> 25 </h5>
                 <h5> 12 </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue with Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13221), but it's not something that can be "fixed".

The columns have padding of 15px on either side, and the smallest column units (col-xs-1) are only 8.333% wide. Eventually screen width is too narrow and the columns wrap.

A simple workaround is to remove the padding:

```
.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/8OVFsrGPJg